# On scrolling tableView in subclass of UIView it appends white ugly marks in View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have made a custom combo files that is using in my project.Those files are here 
[UICombo.h](http://pastebin.com/VzbzSsFu) and [UICombo.m](http://pastebin.com/1jcek1B0).

All is working fine except it add white mark over my super view on which it is added while scrolling.
I am not able to understand why it is happening.Any solution will be appreciated.

Using combo code here ...

```
UICombo *mwCombo;
 mwCombo=[[UICombo alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 48, 177, 30) andItems:nil];
[mwCombo setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin )];
[self.view addSubview:mwCombo];
```

My screen shots are give below.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tableview z-position to -100 that is less than 0.And it is working as I have implemented in your example codes.Try adding following line before adding table view to self in init method in UICombo.m file.

```
[_tableView.layer setZPosition:-100];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `clipsoBounds` property of your `UICombo` or on some of the views that it uses internally to draw itself. If you have structured this class nicely it will manage any other views that get created when it expands and on one of those views you should set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`, perhaps on the table-view itself.

Comment: I have setted both tableview and combo view clipstoboud yes but still working as same

Comment: Try putting the table view inside another view, and make sure that view has the correct frame rectangle - set `clipsToBounds` on that container view. Remember you are building a custom UI control here, so it's not a trivial task and you can't expect UIKit to do everything for you, `UITableView` wasn't intended to be used like that so you can't expect it to behave exactly how you want.